# reference asp server controls from client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

this question might sound silly to some but i just had to make sure.

iv'e got a control which is not visible (visible = false) 
i want it to become visible under certain conditions  for instance onmoueover of a certain textbox ,

can i perform client side events such as this  on server controls ?

iv'e noticed that i can't even give the onmouseover event if the control is set to run at server.

to summarize , is there a way the make a server control visible from the client side with out
having to post back to the server .

thanks for the answer from before but i came across a new problem :

my control is a calendar which is placed inside a content page ,

when i click on a textbox i want it to appear but when it is set to Visible=false 
the client side script isn't able to locate it :

```
     function Show_Calander() {
      debugger;
      var c = document.getElementById('<%= calander1.ClientID %>');
      c.visible = true;
  }

  <input type="text" id="txt_date" runat="server"  onclick="Show_Calander();"/>
  <asp:Calendar ID="calander1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>
```

i can do this form the server side but i just want to increase performance by not going to the server for every little thing.

any ideas how i could make this happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is certainly possible with javascript.  Each control has a `ClientID` property which can be used to reference it from javascript.  Here's a quick example with jQuery on how to make a particular Asp.Net control visible on a click event

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" Runat="server" />
<button id='theButton'>Make it Visible</button>
```

JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#theButton').click(function() {
    var id = '#' + '<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>';
    $(id).show();
  });
});
```